# Rest api set values to undefined using ionic

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm learning Ionic and i'm trying to insert some data calling a API in `node js`. The data is inserted but all the values are setting to undefined in the data base. The strange is that if i call the same service with the same data that i'm calling from the `ionic app` in `Postman` its works ok, so i don't know which can be the problem.

Here is my Ionic code:

```
save(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.contact));
    this.http.post(END_POINT, JSON.stringify(this.contact))
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

The data printed by `JSON.stringify(this.contact)` is:

`{"nombres":"Michael","apellidos":"Montero","email":"email@email.com","telefono":"11111111"}`

Any clue? I've also tried with `FormData` and the same...

[image]

Comment: first off all if you add picture in postman how you input  this.contact then i will help you...

Comment: I've updated the question @Utpaul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far discussion you need to rewrite `save()` function is such way.

```
save(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.contact));
    this.http.post(END_POINT,this.contact)
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

I think you will be helpful.